# NodeJS - Request, does not proceed with POST / JSON

Tags: node.js, ajax, request

Trying to submit a JSON-Object through my site via nodeJS - Request.

```
var options = {
        uri: 'http://localhost/test.php',
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            "longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"
        }
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    });
```

On my test.php script, i am simply writing the $_REQUEST vars via json_encode in a debug file:

```
<?php

file_put_contents('test.debug.txt', "TEST: " . json_encode($_REQUEST) . json_encode($_POST));
```

Apparently the $_POST contains nothing. For a first debug-step, i wrote the parameters in my URL, to check if the PHP Script is working:

```
var options = {
        uri: 'http://localhost/test.php?debug=1',
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            "longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"
        }
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    });
```

And this additional `debug=1` made it so i can see {'debug':1} as an output in my debug file. So my question  right now: What happened to the POST Variables?

Output from the NodeJS Request:

```
0|server  |   request:
0|server  |    Request {
0|server  |      _events:
0|server  |       [Object: null prototype] {
0|server  |         error: [Function: bound ],
0|server  |         complete: [Function: bound ],
0|server  |         pipe: [Function],
0|server  |         data: [Function],
0|server  |         end: [Function] },
0|server  |      _eventsCount: 5,
0|server  |      _maxListeners: undefined,
0|server  |      method: 'POST',
0|server  |      body:
0|server  |       '{"longUrl":""http://www.google.com/"}',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the npm `request` package, the proper way to post json is ([doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#requestoptions-callback)):

```
options = {
  uri: 'http://localhost/test.php',
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"
  }),
  json: true
}
```

Update:
Try this to send as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
options = {
  uri: 'http://localhost/test.php',
  method: 'POST',
  form: {
    "longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"
  }
}
```

Comment: `request(options, function (error, response, body) {` In this line where is `request` coming from? npm request package?

Comment: It's bascially this:
`var request = require('request');`

Comment: Maybe your server not receiving `json`? Try update answer

Comment: It is, because i recently tried the same request via REST Client - which works perfectly fine with JSON Objects as a string

Comment: your debug log is through `request`?

Comment: As you were saying, the header was missing:
```headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }```

I will double check, if this is the case, but you might got it